# Recursive calculation in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, recursive-query

I need to calculate stock as a dinamic and recursive value, as the simple equation:

[image]

n value refers to a periodic time (month, day, year, etc)

Always when a stock value is negative, this is replaced by zero.

How can I calculate this in Big Query? Here is a example:

```html
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 10 entrada, 5  venda, 8 quebra, 8 mes, 2019 ano UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 8 , 3, 9, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 15, 2, 10, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 11, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 10, 5, 12, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 1, 2020  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 2, 2020  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 3, 2020  
)

SELECT entrada, venda, quebra,
  variacao,
  greatest(coalesce(lag(variacao) over (partition by 'project.dataset.table' order by ano, mes),0) + entrada - venda - quebra, 0) as estoque

FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    entrada - venda - quebra AS variacao
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

And the expected result would be:

```
entrada venda   quebra  variacao    estoque
10  5   8   -3  0
12  8   3   1   1
20  15  2   3   4
30  12  2   16  20
20  10  5   5   25
30  12  2   16  41
30  12  2   16  57
30  12  2   16  73
```

But, the results for the code above is:

```
entrada venda   quebra  variacao    estoque
10  5   8   -3  0
12  8   3   1   0
20  15  2   3   4
30  12  2   16  19
20  10  5   5   21
30  12  2   16  21
30  12  2   16  32
30  12  2   16  32
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery does not support recursive operations natively. Try `array_agg()` combined with [JavaScript user-defined function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure), but this approach is not very scalable:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION special_sum(x ARRAY<INT64>)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  var estoque = 0;
  for (const num of x)
  {
     estoque = Math.max(estoque + parseInt(num), 0);
  }
  return estoque;
""";

WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 10 entrada, 5  venda, 8 quebra, 8 mes, 2019 ano UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 8 , 3, 9, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 15, 2, 10, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 11, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 10, 5, 12, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 1, 2020  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 2, 2020  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 3, 2020  
)
select *, 
 special_sum(array_agg(entrada - venda - quebra) over (order by ano, mes rows unbounded preceding)) as estoque
from `project.dataset.table`
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Your solution is definitely better!. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solved using a "internal" sum of all values of stock. Using this:

```html
   WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 10 entrada, 5  venda, 8 quebra, 8 mes, 2019 ano UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 8 , 3, 9, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 15, 2, 10, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 11, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 10, 5, 12, 2019  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 1, 2020  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 2, 2020  UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 12, 2, 3, 2020  
)

SELECT entrada, venda, quebra,
  sum(greatest(entrada - venda - quebra,0)) over (partition by 'project.dataset.table' order by ano, mes) as estoque,
  mes, ano
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: i considered jumping to this question - but see that you have the solution already. I feel like it actually does not work for more generic cases when for example negative stock happen somewhen in the middle of your set of records (as opposed to case of having negative stock at the very beginning as it is in your sample). But I understand that I might be reading your question wrongly and above is actually really what you want. Can  you double check and confirm, so I will not look into this question

Comment: You're right @MikhailBerlyant, when a negative stock occurs in the middle date, this solution doesn't work. I've created this artificial data, but when I extended the solution to real data, some results get wrong. I will try to remake the solution... Do you have any idea about a possible way?